# Use EntityManager with JAX-RS and Jackson in a custom deserializer

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jackson, jax-rs

I have data for a customer formated in JSON :

```
{
    "name":"My Name",
    "company":{
        "id":9
    }
}
```

My entity looks like :

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    String name;

    @Reference
    Company company;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

I want to deserialize this data with Jackson and get a reference for `company` via `EntityManager.getReference(Company.class, id)`. The annotation `@Reference` is a custom annotation that indicates that I want tu use my custom deserializer and retrieve the reference. The goal is to transparently access `company` information in my JAX-RS service endpoint.

My question is: How should I inject or create the EntityManager during the deserialization ?

Here is some code:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContext implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContext() {
        super();
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new CustomModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

In `CustomModule.java` :

```
public class CustomModule extends SimpleModule {
    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        AnnotationIntrospector ai = new CustomAnnotationIntrospector();
        context.appendAnnotationIntrospector(ai);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Finally, in `CustomAnnotationIntrospector.java`:

```
public class CustomAnnotationIntrospector extends AnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public Object findDeserializer(Annotated am) {
        Reference reference = am.getAnnotation(Reference.class);
        if(reference == null){
            return null;
        }
        return CustomDeserializer.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create or injecting the EntityManager during the deserialization seems a weird idea. Why don't you simply retrieve the Company before serving it through webservices?

Comment: I have a lot of "references" to retrieve. It would be great if it was done automatically. But in fact, it may not be a good idea to inject the EntityManager during the deserialization process. I think I will parse my deserialized objects again to resolve references.

Comment: I need to do this exact same thing. Did you ever come up with a solution?